# Trouble with argc and argv

Tags: c++, argv, argc

I am trying to add command line arguments to my programs.  So I was experimenting and cannot figure out this intellisense warning for the life of me.  It keeps on saying it is expecting a ')', but I don’t have any idea why.

Here is the code it does not like:

```
// Calculate average
average = sum / (argc – 1);
```

Then it underlines the subtraction operator.  Below is the full program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float average;
    int sum = 0;

    // Valid number of arguments?
    if (argc > 1)
    {
         // Loop through the arguments, ignoring the first which is
         // the name and path of this program
         for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
         {
             // Convert cString to int
             sum += atoi(argv[i]);
         }

         // Calculate average
         average = sum / (argc – 1);
         std::cout << "\nSum: " << sum << '\n'
                   << "Average: " << average << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // If an invalid number of arguments, display an error message
        // and usage syntax
        std::cout << "Error: No arguments\n"
                  << "Syntax: command_line [space-delimited numbers]"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might try to warn you that you're probably expecting something different from what you're computing. Tip: What are the types of `sum` and `argc`? :-)

Comment: If compiled, this would (most likely) result in 'stray errors', triplet 342, 200, and 223 (octal) (UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2013 ([EN DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)).).

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: What compiler and/or IDE? What version? What is the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 9):

The character you think is a minus sign is something else, so it is not parsed as a subtraction operator.

Your version:

```
average = sum / ( argc – 1 );
```

Correct version (cut and paste into your code):

```
average = sum / ( argc - 1 );
```

Note that calculating an average using integers might not be the best way to do it. You have integer arithmetic on the RHS, which you then assign to `float` on the LHS. You should perform the division using floating point types. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << float((3)/5) << "\n"; // int division to FP: prints 0!
  std::cout << float(3)/5 << "\n";   // FP division: prints 0.6
}
```

Comment: @g-makulik: He has a weird non-ascii unicode character in his program that looks like a minus, but isn't

Comment: @g-makulik you can see the dash now :-)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to compile your code on my machine with g++ 4.6.3 and got the follow error:

```
cd ~
g++ teste.cpp -o  teste
```

Output:

```
teste.cpp:20:8: erro: stray ‘\342’ in program
teste.cpp:20:8: erro: stray ‘\200’ in program
teste.cpp:20:8: erro: stray ‘\223’ in program
teste.cpp: Na função ‘int main(int, char**)’:
teste.cpp:16:33: erro: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
teste.cpp:20:35: erro: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

Looks like there is some strange char in that line. Remove and re-write the line fixed the error.

Comment: It isn't mysterious. 342 200 223 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0x93 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2013 ([EN DASH](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)). It can be searched (and replaced) for by using the regular expression `\x{2013}` in any modern text editor or IDE. Note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u2013` (instead of `\x{2013}`)

Comment: [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) is less cryptic, but, sadly,  less specific: "`error: non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers`". (At least by default.)